# iPad mistakenly loads iPhone storyboard on first time load

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

I have a universal application where I have one storyboard for iPhone and one for iPad. I have a problem where the first time the application gets installed on a device (through TestFlight) the application loads iPhone storyboard. If I re-install the application without uninstalling, the issue auto corrects itself and iPad storyboard loads correctly.

The application is defined as Universal in Target with the 2 different storyboards defined for iPhone and iPad.

Any ideas around what might be wrong?

Comment: There is not enough to say what is going on, please post the code on how you load the specific storyboard and/or any other code which might be useful.